# Looking up fields from multiple table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to show schedules for a student. This is the map out:

```
StudentProfile
-studentid

Registration
-registrationid
-studentid

RegistrationSchedule
-regscheduleid(is not a primary key,, is not unique,,can have a lot of instances)
-registrationdid
-scheduleid

Schedules
-scheduleid
```

I wanted to show all the schedules of a student. I am really frustrated with this. Could somebody make this happen?

Comment: Yup...sounds like you need to learn how to `join`

Comment: i did try but i use in instead of join....sorry for being such a noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the following **should** work, but it's only based on the information you provided (which isn't much) so there are no guarantees:

```
SELECT s.* from Schedules s
join RegistrationSchedule rs on s.scheduleid=rs.scheduleid
join Registration r on rs.registrationid=r.registrationid
join StudentProfile p on r.studentid=p.studentid
WHERE p.studentid=?
```

You'd have to pass a value for the `?` in the WHERE clause in order to get the schedule for a particular student.

Comment: quite sorry but the output was wrong.... it only delivers one output... i have a multiple one and it does not show that

Comment: can you post some sample data from your db? The query should give you what you're looking for, unless your data is different from what you've implied it is.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the MySQL [JOIN Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT * FROM StudentProfile sp 
INNER JOIN Registration r ON sp.studentid = r.studentid
INNER JOIN RegistrationSchedule rs ON r.registrationId= rs.registrationId
INNER JOIN Schedules sc ON rs.scheduleid = schedules.scheduleid
WHERE sp.studentid = DESIREDSTUDENTID
```

This will select all of the columns in each of the tables for the student with the id, DESIREDSTUDENTID. You can get just the data from the schedules for a student by changing the SELECT * to SELECT sc.*

Comment: dont have studentid on my registration schedule

Comment: the code you have given gives only one result....what if i have 2 fields on the registrationschedule table..how can i get multiple results

Comment: The code would return multiple rows if one student has more than one Registration, RegistrationSchedule or Schedule. Are you sure that you should be seeing two rows returned?

Comment: yes...the student has a id which would then be a foreign key to the registration.. that registration also has an id which would be a foreign key to registration schedule....the registration schedule can have many session id's for it would be more like an array that the registration would point out to...i have inserted 2 values that are the same for in the registration schedule table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from StudentProfile sp
   inner join Registration r on r.studentid = sp.studentid
   inner join RegistrationSchedule rs on r.registrationid = rs.registrationid
   inner join Schedule s on s.scheduleid = rs.scheduleid
```

Comment: the code gave only one result... i have multiple scheduleid's for registerschedule table..how can i achieve that